# How to remove beforeunload event listeners added by the iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

How can I remove beforeunload event listeners added by the iFrame?
My case is the iframe I load add some beforeunload events to the DOM, which I want to remove in case the session expires(or say for a particular event) and I don't want to show the confirmation message to the user. So is there any way I can remove event listeners from the iframe using javascript? Any help will be appreciated.

> // parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parent Frame</title>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
        console.log('I am the 1st one.');
      });
      window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
        console.log('I am the 3rd one.');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="child-frame.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

> // child.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Child Frame</title>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
        console.log('I am the 2nd one.');
      });
      window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
        console.log('I am the 4th and last one…');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      ☻
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you'll need to change the way the event listener is added on `child.html` - I gather you can change the code on `child.html`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to reproduce this behavior only on chrome, FF doesn't seem to fire the event across iframes.

One workaround I found (might not be the best), is to remove the iframe before leaving the page :

```
mainWindow.onbeforeunload = e => { iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe) };
```

This way, the event doesn't bubble to the iframe's window anymore.

```js
// toggle the blocking script
inp.onchange = 
  e => window.onbeforeunload = inp.checked ?
    blockMessage :
    null;

function blockMessage(e){
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  }
```

```html
<h3>click "Run code snippet" again</h3>
<label>block iframe's beforeunload<input type="checkbox" id="inp"></label><br>
<iframe id="iframe" src="data:text/html,%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cscript%3Eonbeforeunload%20%3D%20e%20%3D%3E%20%22bye%22%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E"></iframe>

<!-- Decoded iframe content : 
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
   onbeforeunload = e => "bye";
  </script>
  </head>
  </html>
-->
```

Answer (score 3):

write add event listener function separately. so that it can be used to remove the listener.

```
function beforeUnload(event) {
   console.log('I am the 2nd one.');
};
// creating event listeners
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload);

// remove when you don't want the listener
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload);
```

Comment: I have to remove iframe's events from the host

Comment: To what you are referring to host?

Comment: parent html is the host here